# How do I stop form validation by overriding the onsubmit event?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to stop the browser from validating the form on submit. I have overridden the `onsubmit` event to use my own function. Unfortunately, when I submit the form, it is still validated, and my function does not run. The following is the code:

```js
function submitFunction() {
  alert("Name is required.");
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form  onsubmit="submitFunction()">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

How can I fix this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: `event` is probably your problem

Comment: `return false` should do the trick

Comment: @AlonEitan It won't run the `submit` callback at all. So the `event` shouldn't be a problem,

Comment: Quite right @SMAKSS, I missed that. But I still think it's worth mentioning (If the OP will need to use the event inside the function after adding the `novalidate` attribute)

Comment: @AlonEitan Well, it is not necessary to pass `event` to the callback since the `event` keyword will automatically available within the callback scope without passing it directly. So I guess using `event.preventDefault();` won't cause any problem here.

Comment: IMO I don't think you should prevent the native form validation... it's useful and good for accessibility

Comment: I had no idea about that @SMAKSS! I tried it and it worked. Thanks, I learned something new :)

Comment: @Endless I won't. I want to show the messages in a different way compared to the browser default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add to your `form` the attribute called `novalidate` then it will call your function:

```js
function submitFunction() {
  alert("Name is required.");
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="submitFunction()" novalidate>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

From the [documentation of `<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form):

> This Boolean attribute indicates that the form shouldn't be validated when submitted. If this attribute is not set (and therefore the form is validated), it can be overridden by a `formnovalidate` attribute on a `<button>`, `<input type="submit">`, or `<input type="image">` element belonging to the form.